# Admob Show Rates vs Matched Requests

Tags: admob

I'm facing a problem where my app has 4000 matched requests with 4053 network requests which gives me a 99% match rate but my show rate is near 2000.

can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: please see the link https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6158845?hl=en 

The percentage of returned ads that were displayed in the app to the user. It's calculated by dividing impressions by matched requests:

Impressions / Matched requests

For example, if the total number of Matched requests is 80, but your app only shows 60 of these, then the app’s Show rate will be 75%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets make some order:

**network requests**: amount of requests sent from app to admob

**Matched requests**: amount of requests that admob succeeded in filling

**show rate (impression):** actual amount of ads that was shown to the user

Understand that not all of the ads that an app request is eventually displayed to the user. for interstitial for example usually an ad is requested in advance and kept in cache (this is an ad request and a match) and only when the user actually sees the ad it counts as an impression.

Comment: I have a show rate about 58%. Is it low? Is it mainly ads being loaded, kept in cache but not displayed to user or same ads displayed over and over again? Can using mediation increase show rate?

Comment: Don't read to much into show rate. If my app showed 1 ad to everyone that played the game, then immediately cached another ad, that would give a show rate of 50%, as 2 ads were requested, but only 1 was show. What you need it to compare bootups with ads shown. Firebase or some analytics package should help you there.